# 'Unexpected token' syntax error in object returned by arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here is the code in question:

```
const data =
  results.responses.map((response, idx) =>
    { id: idx+1,
      name: response.name,
      email: response.email,
      comment: response.comment
    }
  )
```

I am using babel to translate the es6 code to javascript. This is the error message:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/antkong/dev/project/form.js: Unexpected token (60:14)
  58 |       results.responses.map((response, idx) =>
  59 |         { id: idx+1,
> 60 |           name: response.name,
     |               ^
  61 |           email: response.email,
  62 |           comment: response.comment
  63 |         }
```

Why there is a syntax error there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example JavaScript treats `{` and `}` as a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) instead of object literal. Wrap your object in brackets (`(` and `)`) and it will work.

Corrected code:

```
const data =
  results.responses.map((response, idx) =>
    ({ id: idx+1,
      name: response.name,
      email: response.email,
      comment: response.comment
    })
  )
```